# What is the correctest way to install Qt5 in Gentoo Linux?

Tags: gentoo, qt

I already do following things:

```
# layman -a qt
# cat /etc/portage/package.accept_keywords
=x11-libs/qt-core-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-network-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-dbus-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-declarative-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-demo-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-gui-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-multimedia-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-opengl-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-phonon-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-qt3support-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-script-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-sql-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-svg-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-test-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-webkit-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-xmlpatterns-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-widgets-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-jsbackend-5.9999 **
=x11-libs/qt-xml-5.9999 **
```

And what next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A year and a half late, but if could be of use for anyone. There are two sets:

```
emerge -av @qt5-essentials @qt5-addons
```

for the qt overlay, ofc

Comment: Yes, this is what is exactly expected for those dais.